# Is a data warehouse a good solution for sharing customer data across technologies?

Tags: etl, data-warehouse, enterprise-architecture

I am wanting to be able to share data across all areas of our business in a way that reduces the overall complexity of our infrastructure.

### **The Problem**

Our problem is that we currently have 4 main applications that all connect to our CRM application (Microsoft Dynamics 2011):

[image]

The decision-makers at our firm are currently wanting to upgrade our CRM to the most current version and, then, stay up to date as new upgrades are released (every 2-3 years). Almost all of our applications are rigidly integrated with Microsoft Dynamics so each upgrade is very expensive and risky. I want to design another approach that will reduce this expense and risk.

### **Research**

In 2006, Roger Sessions wrote an article called *A Better Path to Enterprise Architectures* ([here](https://web.archive.org/web/20170310131840/https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa479371.aspx)) which outlines ways to better Business IT systems. One of the central themes in his discussion is reducing complexity, and by arranging die in different ways, he shows that you can exponentially reduce the complexity of systems by partitioning technologies into segments rather than letting any technology connect to any other technology. Jeanne Ross has a great presentation on this topic as well ([here](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=ScHG63YmJ2k)), and she talks about having a digitized platform for sharing core data and services between areas of the business in order to reduce complexity of the overall system and increase agility in responding to current and future business needs.

### **Conclusions**

As I reflect on the lessons from Sessions and Ross, I am confident that we need to take Microsoft Dynamics out of the center of our architecture if we are wanting to overhaul the technology every 2-3 years. We'll just need replace it with something that will allow our core data (mostly customer data) to be shared across applications. I know that data warehouses are often used for aggregating data across the organization. Could this work?

[image]

I understand that data warehouses are mostly used for reporting, so I don't know if having direct connections to the data warehouse would be ideal. However, each application would not need the ability to update any data in the data warehouse. They just need the ability to grab their IDs to set up relationships between global, data warehouse entities (customers) and various unit-specific entities within each application's database.

### **Questions**

Which of these three options would meet my needs: (1) a data warehouse to which all applications connect directly, (2) a data warehouse that feeds data to each application-specific database through overnight updates or (3) something else?

Thanks

Answer (score 3, accepted):

What you're after is a data integration architecture - that doesn't necessarily mean a data warehouse. The pattern you're describing is called "hub and spoke," and it's very common - I'd say you're definitely on the right track for resolving the integration problem you're describing.

[This page](http://tdwi.org/articles/2008/05/27/data-integration-architecture-what-it-does-where-its-going-and-why-you-should-care.aspx) goes into this problem and pattern in much more depth, and it also has a section on the differences between data warehousing and data integration. You've noted that you're aware data warehouses are commonly used for reporting - that's true, and they're also used heavily for analytics, as the link discusses. They're traditionally a data source for business intelligence efforts. This can mean they're not always focused on the kind of data you're interested in - i.e. operational data which your systems need to function, but which might not be of interest for reporting or analytical purposes. Or, they might not function in a way that's helpful for your needs - for instance, traditional overnight ETL loads might not be the best solution if you need your applications to be up-to-date more quickly.

All this is to say that data warehouses can definitely be used as a data hub - the EDW becomes your "master data" source, any data quality processes needed run on the EDW data, and ETL processes fire corrected data back out to the various sources - but you'll probably be better served by researching the topic of data integration than the topic of data warehousing, even if the two share a lot of similarities and can overlap.

If you create a data warehouse without any business intelligence requirements, it might not function very well as a data warehouse. A very suitable data integration/master data solution might not resolve all of the future requirements you have for a data warehouse. Equally, if you were to create a traditional data warehouse after researching data warehousing best practices, it might not fulfill your data integration requirements, or fulfill them in the best way. As the link suggests, separate the two ideas: resolve your data integration problem, and if you want a data warehouse in the future, you can use your data integration solution to help populate it.